# How did Microsoft do it: Abstract method in static class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, static, abstract

As I know, abstract methods can be ONLY exist in abstract classes.
In spite of this, I can see Microsoft did this (in Xamarin.Forms):

```
  public static class DependencyService
  {
    ….
        public static void Register<T>() where T : class;
    ….
  }
```

This is an abstract method in a NON abstract class. How can it be?

Comment: No it's not. It's not abstract. You just can't see its implementation from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is an abstract method in a NON abstract class

No? It is not. Where do you get the idea it is an abstract method? It is a open type method that you can call by providing the type (Register()) and has NOTHING to do with abstract.

Now, you say - it has no body. Sure? It looks a lot more like you just do not SEE the body because you do not have access to the code and this could be a "open reference" style code without access to the source code style (showing signature but not body).

Comment: What...This is new for me. I didn't know there are methods which have body, but we can't see the body... Is there any way to understand that a method in front of us has a body, that we just can't see?

Comment: Yeah. Basically if there is no ACCESS TO THE SOURCE CODE THEN IT CAN NOT SHOW THE SOURCE CODE. SImple like that. Possibly Xamarin has a souce repository that you have not set up.

Comment: Yes, there is (Thanks to @Youssef13) - What I didn't understand  is what the point in not letting people see the source code in VS but, letting them see it in GitHub). Secondly, How did you know that this is the situation. I mean...What is the indication that this method has a body which is just hidden body.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract method **must** have the `abstract` keyword specified.
The method signature in your question:

```cs
public static void Register<T>() where T : class;
```

does **NOT** have the `abstract` keyword.

The `Xamarin.Forms` is an open-source project, you can look at the source code in their GitHub repositroy.

Click [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4dae56ee03198f1ca0b339c32b81d6336615155b/Xamarin.Forms.Core/DependencyService.cs#L61) to see the actual code of the method you're referring to.

Comment: I don't understand the logic...Xamarin didn't want me to have the option to see the code in Visual Studio, but Xamarin agreed I will see it in GitHub?? and how can I know that a method which seems not to have a body, actually has a body that I can watch in another place..

Comment: It's Visual Studio itself that doesn't show the code, nothing special with Xamarin itself. So, you have to look at GitHub to see the implementation (or somehow use a decompiler).